# Something is blocking certain IP addresses on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firewall

I'm using Windows 7 and something is blocking one specific website address.

I've checked

1. Windows firewall rules
2. hosts file entries
3. Policy group rules

I can ping that site and it responds. I can tracert to this site and it works fine. When I try to connect from the browser, the DNS resolves its IP and tries to connect, without success.

I've tried to disable Windows firewall - no result.

I've tried to use Wireshark to understand what's wrong - no result after DNS resolving.

I've tried to connect to this site using other User account - doesn't work.

I've tried to use different tools to connect to the website - doesn't work.

It works when I connect from the other OS (Android Tablet) or a proxy (but still using the same, local network connection and the same outgoing public IP address).

So I suspect there is some stupid hidden component in my OS (I even checked for rootkits) that blocks this particular IP but how to find it?

I could reinstall OS and forget about it, but I'm just curious what the hell is going on :)

Any advices, tools I could use to investigate this case?

Comment: We deal with this all time at my employer.  Permit me to ask some questions.  When you say "disable windows firewall" what exactly did you do?  Is this PC on a domain?

Comment: could it be that the site on that IP is malfunctioning? in wireshark do you see a GET request sent to the server?

Comment: If it works on another OS then it isn't the site.  Although the fact that changing proxies makes it work -- that really makes it look like the proxy is at fault, not something in the OS.

Comment: @MobyDisk I disabled it in Control Panel, I've even tried to clear all the custom rules in Group Policy settings, it seems it's not the Windows Firewall. About that domain thing, what should I check first?

Comment: @FrankThomas nah, I've discovered some others are blocked as well, this is a mystery to me, but I can connect to those sites from other devices in my local network. Yup, the domain gets resolved to the IP address, the GET request is sent, but nothing comes back...

Comment: @Ramhound I've used wrong words, sorry about that. When I choose to use proxy in my browser - it connects without a problem. By default I don't use any proxy, for me it looks like I'm getting blocked on the server side, but I can connect to this server from other devices with the EXACTLY the same public IP address. So - no Win firewall, no proxy, no rootkit, no malware = cannot connect. The same conditions with proxy = can do. So what the hell is going on :) ?

Comment: You are not being blocked by the server.  Like I said something on your end, likely only connected to the PC, is filtering your web traffic.  Lots of routers have basic and even web filtering features.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I figured it out, but now - how to discover this thing :), that's why I came here, first I thought I have some rootkit installed, did a few scans - nothing. I don't have any more ideas what or where to check, but I would like to resolve this matter anyway.

Comment: Connect your PC directly to the modem.  If the websites are still being block then its being blocked by your ISP.  As to the reason other devices might work, some filtering solutions, can be targeted to specific operating systems.  Feel free to update your question to include more information, so we are not abusing the comments, more then we already have.  I pointed out at least one part of your question you should clarify, so go ahead, and do that.